# Simplifying mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to simplify how I query data from my relational database and have no idea where to start.
There are 3 simple tables involved.

#### tbl_people

PersonID, fName, lName

#### tbl_friendship

FriendshipID

#### tbl_friend

FriendID, PersonID, FriendshipID

Currently, I'm just using these queries in a row then looping through the results using php.

```
SELECT FriendshipID FROM tbl_friend WHERE PersonID=$x
SELECT PersonID FROM tbl_friend WHERE FriendshipID=$y AND PersonID <> $x
SELECT fName, lName FROM tbl_people WHERE PersonID=$z
```

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: where is tbl_friendship being used? whats the common ground between these tables?

Comment: I think tbl_friendship should had columns(PersonID, FriendID) adding FriendshipID if you want, and tbl_friend shouldn't exist at all. But you have to explain more the logic of your database.

Comment: it would seem you want to do joins as opposed to divide and conquer the slow way with PHP loops

Comment: FriendshipID and tbl_friendship only exist so that I can have a value that links multiple people. Otherwise, what do I call the link between them? tbl_friend only exists to auto increment the link and allow it to be referenced twice in tbl_friendship

Comment: It has been shown that you only need two tables: tbl_person and tbl_friendship where the latter has two person IDs. The only part to think about now is whether a friendship is regarded one or two way. If Bob considers Jake a friend does that make Bob a friend of Jake's? A one way case is easy to implement, but a two way case needs thinking: Do you want to have two records then, Bob-Jake and Jake-Bob? Or only one, and if only one which? Well, just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

First , its your table tbl_friendship is useless the way it is now, and id_friendship in tbl_friend is also useless , but I understand that you is just doing tests and still make adjustments, with SQL you can do like this:

```
SELECT PE.fName, PE.lName
FROM tbl_people PE
  JOIN tbl_friend FR ON FR.PersonID = PE.PersonID
WHERE PE.PersonID=$x
```

Edit:
Looking in the querys of the question, i think the FK in tbl_friend is PersonID, then a changed this.

Edit2:

`tbl_friendship` need a reference of the Primary Keys of the other two tables:

```
tbl_people
peopleid int PK
fname text
lname text

tbl_friendship
friendshipid int PK
peopleid int FK reference tbl_people.peopleid
friendid int FK reference tbl_friend.friendid

tbl_friend
friendid int PK
fname text
lname text
```

BUT, if you think otherwise, the **Friend** is also a **People** then:

```
tbl_people
peopleid int PK
fname text
lname text

tbl_friendship
friendshipid int PK
peopleid int FK reference tbl_people.peopleid
friendid int FK reference tbl_people.peopleid
```

This way the friend is in the same table people

Comment: if you are using aliases, then use them throughout. Avoids ambiguous error #1052

Comment: tbl_friendship only exists to generate a unique link between 2 records in tbl_friend that can be referenced twice in tbl_friend. If there is a better way to lay this out, please help. I'm very new to this..

Answer (score 0):

It's better to keep it normalized. The way it is your `tbl_friendship` table is useless. Try the following schema:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6329e/21)

**tbl_people**

```
PersonID, fName, lName
```

**tbl_friendship**

```
FriendshipID, PersonID, FriendID
```

So if you want to select all friends of `PersonID = 1` you can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT aa.PersonID, aa.Fname, aa.lName
    FROM tbl_people AS aa
    INNER JOIN tbl_friendship AS bb
    ON aa.PersonID = bb.FriendID
    WHERE bb.PersonID = 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT aa.PersonID, aa.Fname, aa.lName
    FROM tbl_people AS aa
    INNER JOIN tbl_friendship AS bb
    ON aa.PersonID = bb.PersonID
    WHERE bb.FriendID = 2
) AS _aa

ORDER BY _aa.Fname
```

Comment: I thought about using something like this, but then how do I query for friends where the PersonID is listed in the FriendID column in tbl_friendship? e.g. Bob, ID=1, Sam, ID=2. FriendshipID=1, PersonID=1, FriendID=2. I understand that this would work if Bob is querying his friends, but would it still work if Sam queried his? Or would I have 2 entries in tbl_friendship, the other being FriendshipID=2, PersonID=2, FriendID=1?